# KendoUI with angular datepicker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, datepicker

I have the following imports in my index.html

```
<script src="content/js/angular.js"></script>

<link  href="content/js/kendo.common-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link  href="content/js/kendo.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="content/js/kendo.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="content/js/kendo.angular.js"></script>
```

in the module:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", [
    //angular stuff..,
    "kendo.directives"]);
```

and then in my html page

```
<input kendo-date-picker value="10/10/2011" style="width: 100%" />
```

but no datepicker shows up. its just a plain text field with no button or anything. I modified a dojo snippet and it's working just fine. 
[Dojo Snippet here](http://dojo.telerik.com/UtEmO/4)

Anyone know why it's not working?

Comment: You need to give it an ng-model or a k-ng-model

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: We gotta see the demo that is not working.  How are we supposed to help you if you show the working demo?

Answer (score 0):

The html part will show up in the dojo if you modify it to:

`<kendo-date-picker value="10/10/2011"></kendo-date-picker>`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.